# Nixos configuration: `environment.systemPackages` cannot find haskellPackages

Tags: haskell, nixos

I can find haskell packages via `nix-env`:

```
nix-enf -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A haskellPackages
...
```

yet when I try and install them using `environment.systemPackages` in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  haskellPackages.haskellPlatform
];
```

I get the error:

```
error: attribute 'haskellPlatform' missing, at /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:54:5
```

Any ideas? I am intending on using xmonad and want to do haskell dev'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`haskellPlatform` has been removed with the update to GHC 7.8.2, see the mailing list [thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.distributions.nixos/12972) for more details.

You should be able to install any package found via `nix-enf -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A haskellPackages` to `environment.systemPackages`.

Searching for `haskellPackages.haskellPlatform` with `nix-env` should result in the same kind of error that you get during the rebuild:

```
nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A haskellPackages.haskellPlatform
error: attribute ‘haskellPlatform’ in selection path ‘haskellPackages.haskellPlatform’ not found
```

Any valid haskell package can be installed in the environment, for example `xmobar`:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  haskellPackages.xmobar
];
```

Comment: Seems you're right. Having removed `haskellPlatform` I still got `xmonadContrib` and `xmonadExtras` errors. Do they exist still in a different form? Removing those lets me install `xmonad` at least -- should I just install stack instead of `haskellPlatform`?

Comment: @atc `xmonad-contrib`, `xmonad-extras`.